# mysqli_insert_id() always returning NULL

Tags: php, mysqli

mysqli_insert_id() always returning null.I cannot understand the reason for this

```
    $blocksql="insert into blockinfo values(NULL,'$user','$book','$blocktime','$quant1','$flag','$title')";

    mysqli_query($con,$blocksql);
    $id=mysqli_insert_id();
```

Comment: You can get the id after you insert and not before, don't you think?

Comment: still getting the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing a connection to `mysqli_insert_id()` of course it will always be null.

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

Comment: "Of course" it should throw an error... But it doesn't, because PHP.

Comment: Always handle your own errors, boys. This is PHP we're dealing with here!

Answer (score -1):

mysqli_insert_id() always returning null cause you don't  pass mysqli database connection variable parameter .

```
$con = mysqli_connect("Host","UserName","Password","DatabaseName");
$blocksql="insert into blockinfo values(NULL,'$user','$book','$blocktime','$quant1','$flag','$title')";

mysqli_query($con,$blocksql);
$id=mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

I hope this will work for you.Otherwise you can see php manual.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php